# ImportError: No module named mapnik (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: python, import, openstreetmap

An error occurred when `generate_image.py` in `/bin/mapnik` to display image.png

```
dewirobiatul@dewi:~/bin/mapnik$ ./generate_image.py  Traceback (most
recent call last):   File "./generate_image.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mapnik ImportError: No module named mapnik dewirobiatul@dewi:~/bin/mapnik$
```

I try to install mapnik again with command:

```
sudo python scons/scons.py configure INPUT_PLUGINS=all OPTIMIZATION=3 SYSTEM_FONTS=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

but

```
python: can't open file 'scons/scons.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help and solution :)
thank's

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Ubuntu 10.10 here but you could follow the advice on

https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation